# RabbitMQ binding Java

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

i have started learning rabbitMQ and I am a bit confused in binding and routing key.
So what I understood is -routing key is between exchange and queue and on consumer side we create declare exchange again and do channel.queue_bind()  ...
So where does the actual binding happens or how does the queue_bind() method works.
Could anyone explains how it works or am i going wrong somewhere .
Please let me know if any other details are needed.
I am bit confused - I heard that there is some table maintained in exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [the tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html).

They explain about the different exchange types and how queues are bound to exchanges.

For example:

- a queue bound to a fanout exchange needs no key in the binding - a message sent to a fanout exchange goest to all bound queues.
- a queue bound to a direct change with routing key `foo` means that any message published to the exchange with that routing key will be routed to that queue.

When you bind a queue to an exchange, it occurs on the broker; you can use the admin UI (when the plugin is enabled) to explore the queues/exchanges/bindings.